# Customising Google Streetview embed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-street-view

I'm using streetview as an embed in one of my pages. I'd really like to remove the streetview controls though, or at least change their position to the top right, instead of the default top left.

My javascript code is controlling the embed, and the API documentation suggests that "streetview" is just another layer on top of the normal maps API, but I can't find any way of removing them.

Can anyone help?

```
    function initcf1() {
    var myPano = new GStreetviewPanorama(document.getElementById("container"));
    position= new GLatLng(51.479018, -0.215178);
    myPOV = {yaw:378.64659986187695, pitch:-7};
    myPano.setLocationAndPOV(position, myPOV);
    GEvent.addListener(myPano, "error", handleNoFlash);
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initcf1);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Google Maps API Group](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API/browse_thread/thread/ef234393f9513047), this is not possible.  Yes, streetview is another layer on top of the Maps API, but the controls themselves are definitely part of the flash application - not just another layer.

Comment: Hmm yeah, that seems to suggest not!

I've created a new thread in that group, I'll post back here if there is any success.

http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API/browse_thread/thread/eff9954e281bb537#

Answer (score 0):

OK, as far as I've been able to ascertain... the controls are within the flash object and so are impossible to move or modify.

There is next to no information about this anywhere within the google groups or elsewhere on the web :(